# How do you set in Thunder Client the access-token retrieved from collection authentication as an environment variable?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, clientcredential, thunderclient

I have a collection in Thunder Client. In the collection settings I setup the authentication, with Oauth 2 client credentials grant, which generates a token.
The documentation describes that token is saved and will be included in the 'Authentication' header for the requests sent in the collection, and so it does.
But what I want is to access that generated access token to include it in another header in some of the requests.

I tried to saved it in a variable, but I did not succeed.

- I configured the 'Tests' in the collection to 'Set Env Variable', json.access_token setTo {{access_token}} , but it does not work. It seems the Tests are not for the case when token is generated with the  `Generate Token` button.
- I tried to access the token by the name indicated in the OAuth 2 'Advanced Options', but it did not work either.

Either there is something really simple I'm missing, or it is not possible... I checked the documentation for Thunder Client and looked in Internet, but the closest I got was to the work around below.

As work around I created another POST request in my collection which retrieves the access token, and within the 'Tests' tab I can save the the json.access_token from the response body in a variable and use it in other requests.

But I'd still like to know if the access_token can be saved from the `Generate Token` for the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but for anyone else trying. I was also unable to get it to work in the collection but your approach will work if you set the variable in the test on the request instead.